# Stone-Weierstrass Theorem exercise.

Tags: general-topology

Well, this is the exercise:

> Let $E,F$ be two compact metric spaces and $f:E\times F \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Show that  for $\varepsilon >0$, exists a finite system $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of continuous functions from $E$ into $\mathbb{R}$, and a finite system of continuous functiones $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from $F$ into $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $(x,y)\in E \times F$,
>   $$
> \left|f(x,y)-\sum_{i=1}^nu_i(x)\cdot v_i(y)\right|\leq \varepsilon
> $$
>
> **Hint**: Use the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem with the algebra generated by the continuous functions $(x,y)\to u(x)$ and $(x,y) \to v(y)$where $u \in \mathcal{C}(E,\mathbb{R})$ and $v \in \mathcal{C}(F,\mathbb{R})$

So, what I guess is that the following set
$$
\mathcal{A}=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n u_i(x)\cdot v_i(y): u_i\in \mathcal{C}(E,\mathbb{R}),v_i\in\mathcal{C}(F,\mathbb{R})\right\}
$$
is the algebra generated that is in the Hint. But I don't see it clear. How can I see that this is the algebra of the Hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `\left|` and `\right|` to get the sized absolute value bars.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Better yet, \left\lvert \right\rvert to get proper spacing. Unless those two render the same for some reason...

Comment: 1. Every subalgebra of $C(E\times F,\, \mathbb{R})$ that contains $\pi_E^\ast(C(E,\,\mathbb{R}))$ and $\pi_F^\ast(C(F,\,\mathbb{R}))$ must contain $\mathcal{A}$. 2. $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra of $C(E\times F,\, \mathbb{R})$. Then verify that $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies the requirements of the Stone-Weierstraß theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer, sorry, it seems I got a basic doubt. What is the function $\pi_E^*(C(E,\mathbb{R}))$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's the pull-back from $C(E,\,\mathbb{R})$ to $C(E\times F,\,\mathbb{R})$ via the projection $\pi_E \colon E\times F \to E$. You have $\pi_E^\ast(f) = f \circ \pi_E$, and $\pi_E^\ast(C(E,\,\mathbb{R}))$ is the set of all functions on $E\times F$ that you obtain in this way, which are the functions independent of $y \in F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\mathcal A$ in the OP contains the function $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)$ (take $n=1$, $u_1(x)=u(x)$ and $v_1(y)=1$ for all $y$), and in a similar way the function $(x,y)\mapsto v(y)$ for any $u\in \mathcal C(E),v\in\mathcal C(F)$. One can check that $\mathcal A$ is indeed an algebra.

Notice that the algebra generated by the maps of the form $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto v(y)$ contained maps of the form $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)v(y)$, and linear combination of such elements, that is, $\mathcal A$.